# Groovy 2 JsonBuilder Nested Iterable Associations

Tags: json, groovy

I am having 2 issues with the JsonBuilder. I've tried everything I can via researching. This is the closest I have come to solving this but it's not right.

1. arrays for days and agendas do not feature - they come out as non-arrays.
2. Day 2's agendas data is coming out for Day 1's agendas structure for some reason. The underlying data is correct.

Here is the building

```
def root = builder.output {
    days {
        for (Day day : model.days) {
            "$day.name" { 
                agendas {
                    for (Agenda agenda : day.agendas) {
                        "$agenda.name" {
                            name agenda.name
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JSON

```
{ "output": {
    "days": {
        "Day 1": {
            "agendas": {
                "Day 2 Agenda B": {
                    "name": "Day 2 Agenda A"
                },
                "Day 2 Agenda A": {
                    "name": "Day 2 Agenda A"
                }
            }
        },
        "Day 2": {
            "agendas": {
                "Day 2 Agenda B": {
                    "name": "Day 2 Agenda A"
                },
                "Day 2 Agenda A": {
                    "name": "Day 2 Agenda A"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

What I am after is:

```
{ "output": {
    "days": [
        {
            "name": "Day 1",
            "agendas": [
                {
                    "name": "Day 1 Agenda A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Day 1 Agenda B"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Day 2",
            "agendas": [
                {
                    "name": "Day 2 Agenda A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Day 2 Agenda B"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally :)

```
    def builder = new JsonBuilder()

    builder {
        days(days.collect { day ->
            [
                name: day.name,
                agendas: day.agendas.collect { agenda ->
                    name: agenda.name   
                }
            ]
        })
    }
```

Comment: I think you can do that without `collect()`. Just use `days(days) { day->`. Also [name:day.name] this creates map that later is converted to JSON. Instead you can just use DSL

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without `collect()` like this:

```
builder.days(DAYS) { day->
    name day.name
    agendas(day.agendas){ agenda ->
        name agenda.name
    }
}
```

This is output:

```
{
    "days": [
        {
            "name": "Day 1",
            "agendas": [
                {
                    "name": "Day 1 Agenda A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Day 1 Agenda B"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Day 2",
            "agendas": [
                {
                    "name": "Day 2 Agenda A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Day 2 Agenda B"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```